# Resize and change bitrate with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Noobish question here: I need to lower the quality of a video both by scaling it down and changing its bitrate (as an alternative to watermarking it for a client).

I have tried:

```
ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 -vf scale=1200:600 -v:b 10M output_video.mp4
```

Of course, this is wrong. I guess there is another way to append the bitrate command.

Any help?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here you go:

```
ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 -vf "scale=1200:600" -b:v 10M output_video.mp4
```

There were two mistakes here:

- `-v:b`: the bitrate codec(`b`) and the stream selector(`v` for video) were swapped
- `-vf scale`: the filter command should be placed between quotes (you can also use the regular scale option instead: `-s 1200x600`)

Comment: *the filter command should be placed between quotes* --> not required unless there's whitespace or meta-characters.

Comment: You usually don't want to do a single-pass target bitrate encode with libx264. It's not very efficient nor is the quality going to be good. (This is not the case for 10 MBit/s with a 1200x600px video, but more generally speaking…) Use the CRF mode instead if you don't care about the bitrate (`-crf 23`), or use two-pass encoding if you need a certain file size. See: trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264